# Failed to set static IP for BBB network connections

Tags: networking, debian, beagleboard

I follow this guide to set static IP for my BBB with Debian 9.3: [link](http://derekmolloy.ie/set-ip-address-to-be-static-on-the-beaglebone-black/)
.  My /etc/network/interfaces file is modified to be as follow:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Primary / Ethernet port
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
address 192.168.0.20
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1

# Secondary / Wifi RT5370
iface wlxe84e0650ff53 inet static
address 192.168.0.21
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.0.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

After that, my ethernet IP is not set to ...20, but ...18 as before.  On the wifi side, I did not put usb0 because it shows up as wlxe84e0650ff53 when I use ifconfig.  Anybody know why?  The extra settings completely kills it.  I got no wifi, unless I comment out these new lines.  Can someone tell me what went wrong?

Right now, the username and password for the router are not known so I cannot get into it for more info.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

First, there's an error on your eth0 config. You should replace ***iface eth0 inet dhcp*** to ***iface eth0 inet static***. You also need to add the ***auto wlxe84e0650ff53*** before ***iface wlxe84e0650ff53 inet static***. Finally, you need ***wpa-ssid*** and ***wpa-psk*** options for your wi-fi config.
Your **/etc/network/interfaces** should look like something like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Primary / Ethernet port
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
   address 192.168.0.20
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 192.168.0.0
   broadcast 192.168.0.255
   gateway 192.168.0.1
   dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8

# Secondary / Wifi RT5370
auto wlxe84e0650ff53
iface wlxe84e0650ff53 inet static
   address 192.168.0.21
   netmask 255.255.255.0
   network 192.168.0.0
   broadcast 192.168.0.255
   gateway 192.168.0.1
   dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1, 8.8.8.8
   wpa-ssid <Wifi network SSID>
   wpa-psk <Wifi WPA password>
```

In order to know what is your wireless interface name, type `iwconfig` command into your terminal.

P.S I don't fully get why you configure two interfaces in the same network.

Comment: Also, you may safely remove the network and broadcast declarations entirely.

Comment: I read somewhere about WICD, so I installed wicd-gtk and removed network-manager-gnome.  It connects, but does not use the static IP's I set.  Not sure why.  I am switching back to network-manager-gnome and try your settings now.

Comment: The eth0 settings work, but the IP shown on that connection is not the set static IP.  The settings for the wifi do not work.  The network is a WPA2.  Do I need to change anything?  Also, do I need to keep the <> signs?  Not sure why it doesnt work.

Comment: First make sure that the values of **wpa-ssid** and **wpa-psk** are between double quotes.

Exemple:
[...]
wpa-ssid "UbuntuWifi"
wpa-psk "Password"

After applying the configuration, restart networking service with the following command: `sudo systemctl restart networking.service`

Make sure that the service is running (active) properly:  `sudo systemctl status networking.service`

Comment: *timestamp* beaglebone wpa_supplicant [2654]: Delete 'run/wpa_supplicant/wlxe84e0650ff53' manually if it is not used anymore *timestamp* beaglebone wpa_supplicant [2654]: Failed to initialize control interface 'run/wpa_supplicant/wlxe84e0650ff53'.  You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need to remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again........ *timestamp* beaglebone systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.

Comment: ifconfig show wired connection with desired static IP, however the wireless IP is not the set value.

Comment: What is the output of `iwconfig`?

Comment: Deleting said file in wpa_supplicant clears the initialization error, but it still complains about about Failed to initialize control interface....  I unplug the wired connection, and reset the service.  ifconfig tells me the wifi got the static IP, but the web page doesnt load.

Comment: iwconfig: wlxe84e0650ff53  IEEE 802.11 ESSID:off/any ........ seems like wifi wont work somehow with this way of writing to the interfaces file.  I cant understand it.

Comment: ok, after doing some research, I've found a program called `connmanctl`  (already built-in Debian) used specifically on BBB for the configuration of wifi. Here's the forum links on how to use it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/wQPB5DZPhPY

Hopefully, that'll help.
Keep me informed :)

Comment: Ubuntu has also a Manpage about it: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/connmanctl.1.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71296/discussion-between-catx-and-kian).